# Average of last ten months wages

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am having data as below :

```
year    month   Amount 
2012    4   7443.00
2012    5   7443.00
2012    6   7443.00
2012    7   7443.00 
2012    8   7443.00 
2012    9   7443.00 
2012    10  7443.00 
2012    11  7443.00 
2012    12  7443.00 
2013    1   7443.00
2013    2   7443.00
2013    3   9828.00
2013    4   8238.00
2013    5   8238.00
2013    6   8238.00
2013    7   8238.00
2013    8   8238.00
2013    9   8238.00
2013    10  8238.00
2013    11  8238.00
2013    12  8238.00
```

I want average of last ten months amount.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you made *any* attempt to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

this is the sql for ms-server:

```
SELECT TOP 10 year, month, amount FROM your_table_name 
WHERE amount >(SELECT AVG(amount ) FROM your_table_name)
ORDER BY year, month DESC;
```

[[ www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp ] This site page gives you an overview of how to get around with your code](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp)

---

please try this. I did not test it though.

```
SELECT TOP 10 year, month, amount FROM your_table_name 
WHERE amount >(SELECT AVG(amount) AS AverageAmount FROM your_table_name)
ORDER BY year, month DESC;
```

Comment: the result should be 8397

Comment: Simply add up the result and divide by 10;